# Авторизация Google play Services в Unity 2018.3.6

Tags: api, google-play, google-play-services

Я несколько недель не могу заставить свою игру авторизоваться c Google Services, я перебрал очень много сайтов и советов. К слову, код у меня аналогичен документации Google Services, SHA1 ключ совпадает с ключом загрузки в Google play console. Google API также ключ SHA1 как ключ загрузки, мне советовали его туда поставить, но он также не работает, до этого там был ключ подписи который Google подписывает приложения, тоже не работало. Я проверил Logcat, там пишет SIGN_IN статус: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED. Я уже отчаялся, есть ли поэтапная информация как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Я устал решать проблемы и просто ушел в загул. Спустя неделю вернулся и скачал загруженную APK с Google Play и авторизация начала работать. То есть просто нужно подождать. Но все же есть проблемы Авторизация как будто с задержкой. Сначала приходит FeedBack Аутентификация  = False , через время True.